# CakePHP3.1.6 dispatch( Request::createFromGlobals(), new Response() );

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to uses `Vagrant and VirtualBox` to enhance the develop environment on my laptop. So I download the box of `CentOS7.1` and installed `PHP 7.0.1,apache 2.4.18,mysql 5.6.28`. My friend reminded me to add intl extension for using `CakePHP3.1.6`.

While I finished all the install and configure things I add an test html file to the virtual machine. Then I access the virtual machine with `192.168.33.10` which is wrote in `Vagrantfile`. The html works perfectly fine. I put the `CakePHP3.1.6` on the virtual machine but I cannot access properly.The page show me

```
  dispatch( Request::createFromGlobals(), new Response() );
```

and nothing more. I don't know which I missed. Please help.

Comment: I found some thing. My PHP is not working although I get informations when I type php -version. But apache did not run the php code. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for php5.conf and php5.load symbolic links on /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, you can create them by using the following commands

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ln -s ../mods-available/php5.conf
ln -s ../mods-available/php5.load
```